# Is there a Blazor-native way to select all text in an input field on focus?

Tags: blazor

Is there a Blazor-native way to select all text in a text input field on user focus? Something like this in JavaScript:

```
<input onClick="this.select();" >
```

I've built a JS interop function to do this, but I'd rather use something in-the-box.

Answer (score 16):

Steven,

Just use the HTML from your question.

`<input onClick="this.select();" >`

That also works in Blazor

Comment: Well - that is awesome. Thank you!

Comment: An advisory-- if you are preparing a production site, make sure you are testing on all popular machines and browsers.  The Blazor team has to worry about the basics-- but when you foray into Javascript, either use the caniuse webset a lot, or (preferably) purchase at least one of: Windows machine, iPhone, Android phone

Comment: It didn't work for onfocus :-(

Answer (score 0):

Using javascripts `select()` `onClick` is a good solution but comes with a downfall of not being able to set the cursor position. Ideally we could fix this issue using `onFocus` instead of `onClick` but `onFocus` is proven to be unreliable. Instead in the `onClick` we can set a window variable and only focus the element if it's not already focused.

Note: that  `select()` also has some reported issues with mobile Safari. That being said I prefer to use  `setSelectionRange` for highlighting text.

Note: that `select()` after focusing fails in some versions of chrome. This can be resolved by adding a delay after focusing the element.

The complete solution would look like this;

```
<input onclick="@AutoHighlight()">

private string AutoHighlight()
{
    // this.select() reportedly has mobile safari issues. Instead we need .setSelectionRange.
    // Some versions of chrome reportedly can not highlight immediately after focusing. To handle this we add a delay before highlighting.
    return "if (window.focusedElement == this) return; window.focusedElement = this;  setTimeout(function () { window.focusedElement.setSelectionRange(0, window.focusedElement.value.length) }, 100);";

}
```